# css + first load bug + min-height

Tags: css

We forked an editor for upcoming release of our CMS.

See: http://wip.redaxscript.com/home/welcome

The editor uses the css of the current template and loads an additional
fix.css (inside the iframe) to override some rules:

```
* {
    background-image: none !important;
    min-height: 0px !important;
}

#breadcrumbs, #content .sidebar, #footer, #header, #search_form {
    display: none;
}

#content {
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The problem: on first load the **"min-height: 0px !important;"** seems not to work - on second load the height of the editor iframe is 100px like it should be. Other rules like no background (fix.css) are working on first load and get overridden.

Comment: See video made with screentoaster: http://tinyurl.com/y93742p

Answer (score 0):

your iframe seems to have inline styles

```
<iframe frameborder="0" class="textarea" style="display: block; height: 490px;"></iframe>
```

when i removed the height property using firebug, the text area height reduced to 100px

Comment: this.t.style.display='none';
$(this.i.contentWindow).keyup(resizeframe);

i guess the JS auto-resizer is the problem, thanks^^